# Doctrine's hasChangedField to account for changes made in the listener

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a User entity, and I would like to archive it when banned. I have the following `preUpdate` listener:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs) {
    if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('banned') {
        $this->setIsArchived(true);
    }

    if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('isArchived')) {
        /* do Special work here */
    }
}
```

How do I inform `eventArgs` about the field changed inside the handler itself?

Comment: Do you need to update eventArgs? Can't you just keep track of this yourself with a simple boolean? Even if you would update the eventArgs, you would be essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: Its better practice to update eventArgs than use boolean, i found a possible anwser with $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity); but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you edit an entity within the eventArgs, I think you need to persist it and then run the computeChangeSet or computeChangeSets in the UnitOfWork in order for you to use the hasChangedField:

```
$entity = $eventArgs->getObject();
$em = $eventArgs->getObjectManager();
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('banned') {
    $entity->setIsArchived(true);
    $em->persist($entity);
}

$uow->computeChangeSets();

if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('isArchived')) {
    /* do Special work here */
}
```